# VBA Excel Matching value's in sheets and copy rows

Tags: excel, vba

Im pretty new into programming with VBA in excel I got my code working but its just too slow.

Could you guys help me speeding up my task.

Sheet2 has around 42.000 items and sheet1 varies from 100 to 1000

Basicly I look for a value in 2 sheets when there is a match I copy the info into sheet1 from sheet2.

See my code below.

```
Sub CheckAML()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Sheet1LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet2LastRow = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For j = 1 To Sheet1LastRow
        For i = 1 To Sheet2LastRow
            If Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value Then
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 3).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 4).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value
                Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 5).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value
            Else
            End If
    Next i
Next j

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Would also be nice if Sheet2 could be a seperate workbook.

Comment: Consider getting rid of that inner `For` loop and instead using `Range.Find()` Like. `foundCell = Range("A1:A" & Sheet2LastRow").Find(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, 1).Value)` Then you can do `foundCell.Offset(, 2).Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value` and so on. That should dramatically improve performance.

Comment: Can there be multiple matches for a given sheet1 value?  If only a single match then `Application.Match()` is probably the fastest approach.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply, there can be only 1 match between sheet1 and sheet2, sheet2 is basicly the master database that has 42000 unique numbers in column A. What would be the best way to implement application? And is it easy to look in a seperate workbook instead of sheet2?

Comment: "Would also be nice if Sheet2 could be a seperate workbook" Easy. `Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add` then just declare your new worksheet, replace that in your code, and viola

Answer (score 1):

Any reference to a worksheet or cell in VBA is a slow operation.  Only doing a few won't be noticable, but doing many will slow for code down.  Here, in your for loop, you are doing up to 42,000 * 1,000 * 8  = 332,000,000

The key to fast code is to reduce the number of sheet references as much as possible.  Common techniques include

- Moving large blocks of data to / from a Variant Array (and looping that variant array without referencing the sheet)
- Using Range.Find to avoid a loop
- Using VLookup / HLookup / Match to avoid a loop
- Using Range.SpecialCells to reduce the size of a range reference
- Avoid Active: here you have implicit references to the ActiveWorkbook

In your case I'd suggest a combination of a Variant Array and Match, somethng like this

```
Sub CheckAML()
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long
    Dim ws1Range As Range
    Dim ws1Data As Variant
    Dim ws1NewData As Variant
    Dim ws2Range As Range
    Dim rw As Variant
    Dim Newdata As Variant

    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook 'the workbook containing the code
    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks("NameOfWorkbook.xlsm")
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    With ws1
        Set ws1Range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    With ws2
        Set ws2Range = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    End With

    ws1Data = ws1Range.Value
    ws1NewData = ws1Range.Offset(0, 2).Resize(, 3).Formula

    For j = 1 To UBound(ws1Data, 1)
        rw = Application.Match(ws1Data(j, 1), ws2Range, 0)
        If Not IsError(rw) Then
            Newdata = ws2.Cells(rw, 2).Resize(, 3).Value
            ws1NewData(rw, 1) = Newdata(1, 1)
            ws1NewData(rw, 2) = Newdata(1, 2)
            ws1NewData(rw, 3) = Newdata(1, 3)
        End If
    Next

    ws1Range.Offset(, 2).Resize(, 3).Formula = ws1NewData

End Sub
```

<sub>Note: this will preserve any existing data and formulas on ws1, and only overwrite where there is a match</sub>

Comment: I'm getting a  out of range error on set ws1 = wb1. Worksheet(''sheet1") any quick fix?

Comment: Also out of range error on ws1newdata(rw, 1) =newdata(1,1) when I temporarily fixed the code with excel.activesheet on previous comment

Comment: Program basicly tells me ws1range. Value = empty     any way to fix this?